# Пишут ли на С++ под iOS и Windows Phone?

Tags: c++, ios, windowsphone

Знаю,что под Android пишут. А у iOS и Windows Phone есть аналог NDK, или если писать, то исключительно на ObjC и C#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Пишут.

---

Достаточно распространено в мобильном геймдеве, например. В играх намного меньше привязка к API системы, а вот сохранить общий код для кучи разных платформ - бесценно. Примером подобного может служить опенсурсный игровой движок cocos2d-x.

---

На iOS все очень просто и удобно: C++ спокойно сосуществует в одном проекте и даже в одном файле с Objective-C. Возможно использовать как C++ из кода Objective-C, так и наоборот. Все стандартные библиотеки Objective-C могут быть доступны из C++. Естественно, есть некоторые тонкости, связанные с именованием файлов и подключением заголовочных файлов,а так же с памятью, так как в Objective-C есть сборка мусора, а в C++ нет, но, в целом, это мелочи, разработка достаточно проста и удобна. Не уверен, возможно ли это со Swift.

---

Под Windows Phone я напрямую не разрабатывал. Насколько мне известно из общения с WinPhone-программистами, чистый C++ там нужно подключать к проекту в виде динамической библиотеки (.dll) со всеми вытекающими проблемами. При этом, саму программу можно писать на C++/CLI (managed C++).

---

В сравнении с Android разработкой:

- Разработка под iOS на C++ в разы удобнее.
- Под WinPhone я бы сказал - примерно сопоставима по проблемам, но эти проблемы в корне различны.

Answer (score 3):

Пишут
http://habrahabr.ru/post/137469/
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974580.aspx
По идее должно быть проще, чем в андроиде. Интересно было бы услышать комментарии людей которые писали кросс-платформенные приложения под эти три платформы.

Comment: Кроссплатформенные как мне рассказывали пишут на Xamarin, используя C#. В целом хвалят, но получается не так хорошо, как если писать три отдельных приложения под каждую платформу.

Answer (score 1):

На iOS на чистом C++ обычно не пишут, т.к. большинство API написанно на Objective-C. Однако пишут на Objective-C++, который по сути является надстройкой над C++.

Answer (score 0):

Вообше есть возможность писать под C++. Micrasoft дает это решение через VisyalStudio + Xamarin с помощью него нет проблем писать для мобильных устройств. Я сам использовал те же связки технологий но на языке C#, но не думаю что будет какая-то проблема с C++ тот же принципы будет и работать написанное и на этом языке.